# JQ: add variable property to existing object

Tags: json, syntax, environment-variables, jq

I'm trying to add variable properties to some existing json

```
{
  "item1": {
    "proerty1": "test"
  },
  "item2": {}
}
```

So if I do something like this it works

```
echo $contents | jq --arg ITEM1 $item1 '.[$ITEM1].property2 = "test2"'
```

But when I try to add more arguments like this it fails:

```
echo $contents | jq --arg ITEM1 $item1 --arg PROPERTY2 $property2 --arg VALUE $value  '.[$ITEM1].[PROPERTY2] = $VALUE'
```

The error I get is:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[$ITEM1].[PROPERTY2] = $VALUE
jq: 1 compile error
```

So I guess += operator wouldn't be the correct way to do this with variables. What would be the correct way to add a propetry where the whole path .item.property and the value itself are variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jq filter should be:

```
.[$ITEM1][$PROPERTY2] = $VALUE
```

Your query has an extra `.`.

#### An alternative:

You could also use `setpath/2`, e.g.

```
setpath([$ITEM1,$PROPERTY2]; $VALUE)
```

#### Aside

It's usually best to quote your shell variables, e.g.
`echo "$contents" ...`